# calling functions between two different classes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oop

I've got a small scenario to call functions in two different classes.

```
method
{
    NSLog("printing variables 1 & 2 of secondClass.m");
}
```

How to call firstClass method and send those variables to the the class for printing?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the type of function you want to call you could create a static function. To do so just declare the function like `+ (void)printA:(int)a andB:(int)b;`

and call it with `[Class2 printA:a andB:b]` without an instance. Or if you want to call a non static method you could use a delegation protocol.

You can create a protocol like

```
@protocol PrintJobReceiver
- (void)printVariableA:(int)a andB:(int)b;
@end
```

have it be conformed by class2

```
@interface Class2: NSObject <PrintJobReceiver> { }
@end
@implementation Class2
- (void)printVariableA:(int)a andB:(int)b
{
   NSLog(@"a: %i b:%i",a,b);
}
@end
```

and set a delegate at `Class1` you will then use to print (you will want to pass an instance of Class2)

```
@interface Class1:NSObject
{
   id<PrintJobReceiver> delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic,readwrite, retain) id<PrintJobReceiver> delegate;
@end
@implementation Class1
@synthesize delegate;
@end
```

then you can call `[delegate printVariableA:a andB:b];` within Class1. I usually use this instead of passing a reference to the whole class in order to only show the functions that are supposed to be used by the class (and you don't get tempted to use functions you shouldn't)